# Mongodump pipeline into docker swarm

Tags: mongodb, docker-swarm, mongodump

I've issue with dumping data from mongo container into swarm. I can't use `run` into swarm, I can't connect other container (run`'mongodump` because main network not manually attachable). 
I googled this issue and I've found only solutions with `docker-compose` `--link` which doesn't work in swarm.

My plane was:

1. Run other `mongo` container with command `mongodump --host
   main_mongo_container --out some_volume`.
2. Compress dump into `tar`
3. Upload dump onto S3.
4. Run script in cron.

I don't have enough experience for solving this issue myself. Had anyone experience in automatization dumping mongo data from swarm container onto s3?

Many thanks in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Why not run a swarm service that runs an hourly back and then you can automate it with a script to upload where you need it, or just store it in an EBS volume. Here's a [simple example using digitalocean block storage](https://github.com/BretFisher/dogvscat/blob/master/stack-ghost.yml#L47-L60).